# Share a fragment with several classes?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wonder how I can best create a progress bar fragment. It must be usable by every other class of course.

At the moment I have just a ProgressBarFragment, which has public setVisible method. Getting the Fragment through FragmentManager I can set it visible or not. But is this the right way to do these sort of actions?

```
public class MyActivity exetends FragmentActivity {
    void setVisibility(int visible) {
        ProgressBarFragment fragment = (ProgressBarFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_progress_bar);
        fragment.setProgressBar(visible);
    }
}
```

And of course I have several other Fragments which uses this code too, to trigger the progress bar.

```
public class ProgressBarFragment extends Fragment {
    public void setProgressBar(int visible) {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(visible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor this code into a static method of your `ProgressBarFragment`

```
class ProgressBarFragment {
    //...
    static void setVisibility(Activity parent, int visible) {
           ProgressBarFragment progressBar =
                   (ProgressBarFragment)parent.getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_progress_bar);
    progressBar.setProgressBar(visible);
    //...
}
```

So then you will be using `ProgressBarFragment.setVisibility(yourActivity, 1)` everywhere.

Comment: OK although I don't like static classes or methods, this seems to be a quite good solution.

Comment: @membersound It's static *fields* that can cause memory leaks in Android as they can keep otherwise unneeded references forever.